# How to create a 3D invert mask shader in Unity Engine?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, shader, game-engine, hlsl

I have one sphere and one cube. I want to use the cube as mask. i followed this tutorial on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vFwTt4isDY . but i want invert the mask. the intersection between the cube and the sphere should be visible. (the cube is a transparent).

check this image to get more information [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3599J.jpg)

the cube has material with the following shader

```
Shader "Custom/Mask"
{
    SubShader
    {
      Tags{"Queue" = "Transparent+1"}
      Pass
      {
        Blend Zero One
      }
    }
}
```

And the sphere contains the following script

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MaskObject : MonoBehaviour
{
   private void Start()
 {
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.renderQueue = 3002;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need stencil buffer: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/SL-Stencil.html